# Count field in django?

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have a model

```
class Entity(models.Model)
    count = models.IntegerField()'
```

Question: Is there a field type in django that can help me increase the value of count anytime an action is taken. I'm currently thinking of updating the value every-time. But I feel that might not be efficient since this involves reading the current value then increasing by one

Comment: You can use an F()-expression (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F) to at least prevent the extra read operation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about if there are any model fields that will help, but you can prevent the extra database operation using an [F()-expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F):

```
# Given this model class:
class Entity(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField()

# Increment like this:
entity_qs = Entity.objects.filter(pk=some_pk)     # Note: This does not fetch!
entity_qs.update(count=F('count')+1)              # Single SQL update statement
```